# Code::Blocks + Android NDK

Tags: c++, android-ndk, codeblocks, adb, android-debug

Как правильно скрестить `Code::Blocks` + `Android NDK` чтоб в том числе и дебаг работал (pass to ADB?). Возможно есть мануал, или готовый профайл настроек.
В поиске на эту тему крайне не много.. кроме упоминаний что это возможно.

P.S. поставить Android Studio пожалуйста не предлагать.

Comment: А зачем это может понадобится? Проект Code::Blocks вроде не особо живой. Использовать wxWidgets под андроид - затея сомнительная.

Comment: @VTT, Многие им пользуются, например я :) он лёгкий, кроссплатформенный и в общем удобный, не требовательный к ресурсам, по факту работает с любой средой сборки - вопрос рук. А вот при чем `wxWidgets` в Андроид я не понял, `C::B` написан на нем, но это не повод этим виджетом пользоваться как фреймворком для собственного кода.

Comment: Да, ещё добавлю, `C::B` отлично работает в пакетной сборке в автоматическом режиме, очень удобный и легко интегрируется.

Comment: Вот например как использовать `C::B` с [`devkitPSP`](https://gamedevtodied.blogspot.com/2016/04/playstation-portable-psp-getting-start.html) - полезный обзор, может пригодиться кому.

Comment: Хмм, когда я пробовал Code::Blocks в последний раз, там не было ни полноценной подсветки синтаксиса, ни полноценной отладки, не говоря уж о продвинутых фичах, типа автодополнения, рефакторинга, подсказок с выведенными типами и развернутыми макросами и т.п. Попробовал сейчас - все осталось как было. Самый свежий из компиляторов, поддерживаемых из коробки - VS2010. Я могу только констатировать, что Code::Blocks мертв...

Comment: Вопрос свистелок это вопрос вкуса, конечно он 'обделен' разными авто-сенсами-продвинутой-подсветкой итд. Но это наверно к лучшему, с точки зрения скорости работы и потребляемых ресурсов. Лаконичность иногда более к месту, ИМХО, чем красивый хвост 'павлина' :) Кстати, рефакторинг в нем есть, хоть и простенький конечно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнем с малого, как прикрутить `Android NDK` к `C::B`

Есть два пути:

- 1. прописать на каждую платформу свой профиль, с исполняемыми файлами согласно платформе. На мой взгляд утомительно, много всего и непонятно зачем. С учетом что если собирать одно и тоже под все платформы, то объем телодвижений с переключением конфигураций довольно велик.
     У меня по умолчанию собираются `arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, x86, x86_64`.
- 2. использовать родную систему сборки `ndk-build`. Это самое простое и изящное решение, не вступающее в конфликты с большинством проверок `C::B`, но, в настройках `C::B` важна каждая деталь, схема довольно капризная, и при неточностях может легко ломаться.

#### Интеграция Android NDK

---

Идеология и манера сборки приложения с использованием тулчейна `Android NDK` максимально приближена к типовому поведению `C::B`, логика процессов:

- сборка в режиме `Release`- этапы: всегда новая сборка приложения, копирование его на устройство, запуск приложения. Все действия отображаются в консоле `C::B`.
- сборка в режиме `Debug`- этапы: всегда новая сборка приложения, копирование его на устройство, копирование `NDK-парт` файлов для отладки `gdbserver`, `gdb.setup`, запуск `gdbserver` на устройстве, ожидание подключения дебагера `GDB` для отладки.
- режим `запуска приложения`- этапы: запуск на устройстве приложения с выводом результатов в консоль.
- режим `Отладка -> Старт` - этапы: всегда новая сборка приложения, копирование его на устройство, копирование `NDK-парт`файлов для отладки `gdbserv`, `gdb.setup`, запуск `gdbserv` на устройстве, автоматическое подключение дебагера `GDB`и переход в режим отладки.
- в режимах `Debug`, `Отладка -> Старт`, окно запускаемого `gdbserver` стартует в минимизированном состоянии и автоматически закрывается по окончани отладки.

#### Файлы шаблона:

Сам проект `C::B`, важные секции:

- `<Build><Option output>` - указывает на скрипт дистанционного запуска приложения на устройстве - `RunRemote.cmd`. Скрипт генерируется автоматически.
- `<Build><Option compiler="android_ndk-build">` - это обработанное название компилятора в настройках `C::B` - `Android NDK-Build`. Как завести учетную запись нового компилятора, показано ниже.

В секции `<Extensions><debugger><remote_debugging>` находятся настройки дистанционной отладки, реализованной с помощью `GDB`:

- `options ip_address="127.0.0.1" ip_port="59999" extended_remote="0"`, если есть необходимость изменить номер порта, то это так-же необходимо сделать в `Makefile`. Если опция `extended_remote` будет отличной от нуля, окно дистанционно запущенного `gdbserver` не закроется автоматически после отладки.

> **AndroidNdkTemplate.cbp** - файл проекта `C::B`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<CodeBlocks_project_file>
    <FileVersion major="1" minor="6" />
    <Project>
        <Option title="C::B Android Ndk project Template" />
        <Option makefile_is_custom="1" />
        <Option pch_mode="2" />
        <Option compiler="android_ndk-build" />
        <Option check_files="0" />
        <Build>
            <Target title="Release">
                <Option output="RunRemote.cmd" prefix_auto="0" extension_auto="0" />
                <Option type="1" />
                <Option compiler="android_ndk-build" />
            </Target>
            <Target title="Debug">
                <Option output="RunRemote.cmd" prefix_auto="0" extension_auto="0" />
                <Option type="1" />
                <Option compiler="android_ndk-build" />
            </Target>
        </Build>
        <Compiler>
            <Add option="-Wall" />
        </Compiler>
        <Unit filename="main.c">
            <Option compilerVar="CC" />
        </Unit>
        <Extensions>
            <code_completion />
            <envvars />
            <debugger>
                <search_path add="obj/local/armeabi-v7a" />
                <search_path add="obj/local/arm64-v8a" />
                <search_path add="obj/local/x86" />
                <search_path add="obj/local/x86_64" />
                <remote_debugging target="Debug">
                    <options conn_type="0" serial_baud="115200" ip_address="127.0.0.1" ip_port="59999" additional_cmds_before="set solib-search-path obj/local/armeabi-v7a&#x0A;file obj/local/armeabi-v7a/hello_world&#x0A;" />
                </remote_debugging>
            </debugger>
        </Extensions>
    </Project>
</CodeBlocks_project_file>
```

#### Исходные файлы управления сборкой в директории `NDK` проекта:

---

> **Application.mk** - установки параметров сборки:

```
APP_ABI := all
APP_STL := c++_static
APP_OPTIM := debug
APP_PLATFORM := android-22
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := Android.mk
```

> **Android.mk** - собственно и является мейк-файлом уникальным для каждого `NDK` проекта (приложения):

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := hello_world
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./main.c
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := ./
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

> **Makefile** - непосредственно запускается `C::B`:

```
PLATFORM := armeabi-v7a
NDKROOT  := C:\__BuildSource\__LIB__\android-ndk-r20-beta2
PROJECT  := $(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
BUILDTAG := $(filter-out $@,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
BUILDOPT := 

include Application.mk
include $(APP_BUILD_SCRIPT)

ifneq ($(APP_ABI),all)
    PLATFORM = $(APP_ABI)
endif

ifeq ($(BUILDTAG),Debug)
    BUILDOPT = V=1 NDK_DEBUG=1
else
    BUILDOPT = -j 4
endif

all: allndk
Debug: allndk adbsetup adbdebug buildscript rundebug
Release: allndk adbsetup adbexec buildscript
cleanDebug: clean
cleanRelease: clean
cleanall: clean

allndk:
    @echo '==== Build $(BUILDTAG) -> $(APP_ABI) platform -> active device: [ $(PLATFORM) ] ===='
    @Cmd.exe /C $(NDKROOT)\ndk-build.cmd NDK_APPLICATION_MK=$(PROJECT)Application.mk NDK_PROJECT_PATH=$(PROJECT) $(BUILDOPT)

clean:
    @echo '==== Clean ===='
    @Cmd.exe /C $(NDKROOT)\ndk-build.cmd NDK_APPLICATION_MK=$(PROJECT)Application.mk NDK_PROJECT_PATH=$(PROJECT) clean
    @Cmd.exe /C adb.exe shell rm -f /data/local/tmp/$(LOCAL_MODULE)

adbsetup:
    @echo '==== ADB SETUP: [ $(PLATFORM) ] ===='
    @Cmd.exe /C adb.exe push $(PROJECT)libs\$(PLATFORM)\$(LOCAL_MODULE) /data/local/tmp/$(LOCAL_MODULE)
    @Cmd.exe /C adb.exe shell /system/bin/chmod 0777 /data/local/tmp/$(LOCAL_MODULE)

adbexec:
    @echo '==== ADB RUN: [ $(PLATFORM) ] ===='
    @Cmd.exe /C adb.exe shell /data/local/tmp/$(LOCAL_MODULE)

adbdebug:
    @echo '==== GDB Debug: [ $(PLATFORM) ] ===='
    @Cmd.exe /C adb.exe push $(PROJECT)libs\$(PLATFORM)\gdb.setup /data/local/tmp/gdb.setup
    @Cmd.exe /C adb.exe push $(PROJECT)libs\$(PLATFORM)\gdbserver /data/local/tmp/gdbserver
    @Cmd.exe /C adb.exe shell /system/bin/chmod 0777 /data/local/tmp/gdbserver

rundebug:
    @Cmd.exe /C DebugRemote.cmd

buildscript:
ifeq (,$(wildcard ./RunRemote.cmd))
    @echo "adb.exe shell /data/local/tmp/$(LOCAL_MODULE)" >RunRemote.cmd
endif
ifeq (,$(wildcard ./DebugRemote.cmd))
    @echo "adb.exe forward tcp:59999 tcp:59999" >DebugRemote.cmd
    @echo "start \"$(PLATFORM) GDB server\" /MIN adb.exe shell /data/local/tmp/gdbserver :59999 /data/local/tmp/$(LOCAL_MODULE)" >>DebugRemote.cmd
    @echo "exit" >>DebugRemote.cmd
endif

.PHONY: clean all
```

Файлы `Application.mk` и `Makefile` являются универсальными для всех проектов собираемых с помощью `NDK` и не требуют правок.

Для понимания структуры где чего лежит в проекте `NDK` приложения, приведу дерево:

```
│   Android.mk
│   AndroidNdkTemplate.cbp
│   Application.mk
│   main.c
│   Makefile
│   
├───libs
│   ├───arm64-v8a
│   │       gdb.setup
│   │       gdbserver
│   │       hello_world
│   ├───armeabi-v7a
│   │       gdb.setup
│   │       gdbserver
│   │       hello_world
│   ├───x86
│   │       gdb.setup
│   │       gdbserver
│   │       hello_world
│   └───x86_64
│           gdb.setup
│           gdbserver
│           hello_world
│           
└───obj
    └───local
        ├───arm64-v8a
        │   │   hello_world
        │   ├───objs
        │   │   └───hello_world
        │   └───objs-debug
        │       └───hello_world
        │               main.o
        │               main.o.d
        ├───armeabi-v7a
        │   │   hello_world
        │   │   
        │   ├───objs
        │   │   └───hello_world
        │   └───objs-debug
        │       └───hello_world
        │               main.o
        │               main.o.d
        ├───x86
        │   │   hello_world
        │   │   
        │   ├───objs
        │   │   └───hello_world
        │   └───objs-debug
        │       └───hello_world
        │               main.o
        │               main.o.d
        └───x86_64
            │   hello_world
            │   
            ├───objs
            │   └───hello_world
            └───objs-debug
                └───hello_world
                        main.o
                        main.o.d
```

#### Вид настроек проекта из GUI `C::B`:

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обязательно указать возможные пути где расположены объектные файлы с отладочными символами:

- `obj/local/armeabi-v7a`
- `obj/local//arm64-v8a`
- `obj/local/x86`
- `obj/local/x86_64`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо добавить команды `GDB` передающие информацию о нахождении отладочных символов для платформы подключенного устройства:

- `set solib-search-path obj/local/armeabi-v7a` - расположение отладочных символов для активного устройста.
- `file obj/local/armeabi-v7a/<имя приложения>`  - имя отлаживаемого приложения.

#### Вид настроек компилятора в `C::B`:

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### Дополнительное меню отладки `NDK` приложения:

---

Оба используемых в меню скрипта имеют фиксированное имя и генерируются автоматически, во время исполнения `Makefile`, для удобства разумно добавить их в меню:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Метод отладки приложения состоит из типовых действий, например через `F8` или меню `Отладка -> Старт`. Как только запустился дебагер, вам надо вызвать из созданного меню пункт `ADB Debug Remote server`, этой командой вы запустите `GDB сервер` на устройстве, который запустит ваше приложение. Вы подключаетесь к `GDB серверу` дистанционно и можете проводить сеанс отладки.
В режиме `Debug` запуск дистанционного сервера происходит автоматически и не требует вызова данного пункта меню.
Смотрите скриншот настроек дебагера в проекте выше.

Данная схема запуска отладки поддерживает и не рутированные устройства.

#### Глобальные настройки дебагера для `NDK` выглядят так:

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### Отладка на устройстве:

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### Результат сборки приложения толчейном `NDK`:

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### Преимущества использования NDK:

В отличии от статической сборки под определенную платформу:

- Не нужно компилировать двоичные файлы статически, поэтому размер выходного двоичного файла будет меньше.
- Можно использовать android `C/C++` библиотеки, такие как liblog, чтобы иметь возможность иметь вывод в logcat из аппликации.

#### Возможности данного решения:

- не требуется рутированного устройства
- полноценная отладка сборки, без дополнительных инструментов (набор инструментов NDK)
- полноценная сборка в `Debug/Release` режимах
- полноценный запуск приложения (с устройства)
- авто запуск/остановка `gdbserver` с устройства
- не требуется оберток из `Gradle/Java` кода, работает напрямую с устройством

Полный код HOWTO `NDK C::B template` разместил на [github](https://clnviewer.github.io/Code-Blocks-Android-NDK/)